# Изменение атрибутов в XML

Tags: c#, xml, xmlparser

Добрый день. Eсть xml ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2011-03-18T11:27:40.2285156</Date>
    <Author>TU-S-W8-01\artem</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2011-03-18T05:00:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" 
      </Command>
      <Arguments>-S .\SQLExpress -i"C:\SQL Backup\SQL_script\FullDatabaseBackup.sql"
      </Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Нужно загрузить этот xml, изменить значение атрибутов `<Command>` и `<Arguments>`, и сохранить как отдельную xml с измененными атрибутами. 
Как загрузить и сохранить понятно, а вот как именно изменить атрибуты в загруженной xml? 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Воспользоваться методом [XmlElement.SetAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1ah1zbw.aspx)